# Requesting help with retags for Zend Framework following its migration to Laminas Project

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, synonym-removal-request

I am one of the Technical Steering Committee of the Laminas Project.
I need help with tag maintenance following [archival of Zend Framework on 1 January 2020](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2020-01-24-laminas-launch) and its migration to the new Laminas Project.

[Laminas Project](https://getlaminas.org/) is an official continuation of Zend Framework under the Linux Foundation governance.

I request help with the following changes:

- Tag [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas) should be created by staff, as it is not allowed to be created normally since it is too close to [lamina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lamina)
- New tag [laminas-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-project) aliased to [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas)
- [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) should be retagged and set as a synonym for [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas)
- Tag [mezzio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mezzio) created for Mezzio, Zend Expressive previously
- [zend-expressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-expressive) should be retagged and set as a synonym for [mezzio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mezzio)
- Tag [laminas-api-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-api-tools) created for Laminas Api Tools, Zend Apigility previously.
- [apigility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apigility) should be retagged and set as a synonym for [laminas-api-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-api-tools)
- Remove synonym [zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend) for [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) as it was not entirely correct and now makes no sense

Zend Framework is frozen and no longer maintained, but all previous component releases were rewritten and available as laminas components with migration and compatibility tooling. Support for Zend Framework users is now provided by the same community and maintainers under Laminas Project.

---

### laminas

```
Laminas Project, previously Zend Framework, is an open source object-oriented general purpose framework implemented in PHP and licensed under the New BSD license.

Laminas Project is comprised of following subprojects:
- Laminas components
- Laminas MVC framework (tag laminas-mvc)
- Mezzio, previously Expressive (tag mezzio)
- Laminas Api Tools, previously Apigility (tag laminas-api-tools)
```

Questions tagged with [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) will be retagged as [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas)

### laminas-mvc

````
Laminas MVC, previously Zend Framework MVC, is an open source object-oriented event-driven web application framework using Model-View-Controller pattern and implemented in PHP. It is a part of Laminas Project and built on top of Laminas components. 

Questions tagged with [tag:zend-framework-mvc] will be retagged as [tag:laminas-mvc]

mezzio
------
```txt
Mezzio, previously Expressive, allows you to write PSR-7 middleware applications for the web like APIs, Websites, Single Page Applications and more. Mezzio is a part of Laminas Project, previously Zend Framework.
````

Questions tagged with [zend-expressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-expressive) will be retagged as [mezzio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mezzio)

### laminas-api-tools

```
Laminas Api Tools, previously Apigility by Zend Framework, is a PHP API Builder designed to simplify creating and maintaining structured APIs. It is used to build APIs that enable mobile apps, developer communities, and any other consumer controlled access to your applications using PHP.
```

Questions tagged with [apigility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apigility) will be retagged as [laminas-api-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-api-tools)

Comment: Please provide example questions to be tagged with the new tag.

Comment: Please also provide tag wiki and tag usage guidelines/excerpt in your question.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I would prefer to edit tag wiki in place once the tag is created. That would allow me to collaborate with other maintainers for a good informative wiki page. Would excerpt be sufficient at this time?

Comment: Yes. You will still need to provide example questions to be tagged with the new tag, otherwise unused tags will get deleted.

Comment: @SamuelLiew my understanding is that existing questions under respective tags will get retagged when original tags are set as synonyms.

Comment: So what you're asking for is a rename of zend-framework to laminas?

Comment: I suppose so, yes. Problem is we migrated package versions only back to 2.0. Questions about same version would be valid for both ZF and Laminas more or less, but Zend Framework 1 questions are not disambiguated. I would love to leave them behind but I don't know of a way to identify them. Same for MVC, however it was most used for zf2 and up. Apigility/Expressive is a straight rename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Created [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas), without merging/re-tagging questions from [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework), since there will be questions that will not be suitable for [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas)
- Did not create synomyn from [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) > [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas), which can be decided at a later date
- Added lang-php for syntax highlighting for questions tagged [laminas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas)
- Added synomyn [zend-expressive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-expressive) > [mezzio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mezzio), merging can be decided at a later date once the [tag wiki and usage guidance is added](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/143535)
- Added synomyn [apigility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apigility) > [laminas-api-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-api-tools), merging can be decided at a later date once the [tag wiki and usage guidance is added](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/143534)
- I don't see any need to create a synonym for [laminas-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laminas-project) since it's not used

---

Backup of zend-expressive tag wiki:

`Expressive allows you to write PSR-7 middleware applications for the web like APIs, Websites, Single Page Applications and more. Expressive is part of Zend Framework.`

```
[Zend Expressive][1] is built on top of [Zend Stratigility][2] which is a [PSR-7][3] middleware foundation for building and dispatching middleware pipelines. It provides a minimalist PSR-7 middleware framework with routing, DI container, templating (optional) and error handling (optional) capabilities.


  [1]: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive
  [2]: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility
  [3]: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/
```

Backup of apigility tag wiki:

`A PHP API Builder designed to simplify creating and maintaining structured APIs. It is used to build APIs that enable mobile apps, developer communities, and any other consumer controlled access to your applications using PHP.`

```
Apigility is an API Builder designed to simplify creating and maintaining structured APIs. It is used to build APIs that enable mobile apps, developer communities, and any other consumer controlled access to your applications using PHP.

https://www.apigility.org/
```

Comment: I see that original tags are set as synonyms, but existing questions were not affected. Eg they are listed when [tag:mezzio] is viewed, but with the [tag:zend-expressive]. Is it how it is intended to be and will remain that way? It is actually perfect and what I wanted but didn't know was possible.

Comment: Great, no need to merge the tags then.

Comment: [tag:zend-framework] can be set as a synonym for [tag:laminas] too then, since those old ZF1 questions will remain tagged as they were